# Implementing Generic Interfaces for collections of widgets?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, collections

We're attempting to build a somewhat basic reporting system for our analytics team to use. It's our third or fourth iteration of the same system, but we're doing a consolidation and rewrite of a large portion of the backend logic to make generating reports easier going forward.

One issue we're having is forming the interfaces that will be implemented by our reporting widgets in order to push them through to our `ViewComponents`.

An example of a couple widgets may look something like the following:

```
public interface IWidget<T> 
{
    WidgetType WidgetType { get; set; }
    string WidgetName { get; set; }
    T ViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class ChartWidget : IWidget<Chart>
{
    public WidgetType WidgetType { get; private set; }
    public string WidgetName { get; set; }
    public Chart ViewModel { get; set; }

    public ChartWidget() {
        WidgetType = WidgetType.Chart;
    }
}

public class HeadlineBarWidget : IWidget<HeadlineBarData>
{
    public WidgetType WidgetType { get; private set; }
    public string WidgetName { get; set; }
    public HeadlineBarData ViewModel { get; set; }

    public ChartWidget() {
        WidgetType = WidgetType.HeadlineBar;
    }
}
```

But the report will contain a collection of widgets, and that collection will need to be iterated over in the View in order to fetch the proper ViewComponents and supply them with the matching model that they expect. Unfortunately, it appears most collection types need to ensure type safety, and I need a way to make this a bit better. As it stands now, our `IWidget` object defines ViewModel as an `object`, and I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: I am not clear on what your question is JD.

Comment: I'm effectively trying to find a solution on having collections of generic types when the generics may be different for each type, but they all implement the IWidget interface.

Comment: What you ask is not possible, each closed generic type is a complete different type from the others. Your idea of a `IWidget` interface with properties like `object ViewModel` and `Type ViewModelType` is the only viable way (that's the same approach of other frameworks, like MVC, in model binding).

Comment: You should also consider the use of attributes to enrich your `IWidget` implementations with properties which are of the entire class, and not of the single instance (e.g. it appears to me it is redundant to initialize your `WidgetType` property inside each class constructor).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma can you elaborate on the attributes?